# Combine JS from within the JS

Tags: javascript, performance, requirejs, bundle

I have a javascript library which is used by web clients. The library has a main JS file and bunch of other supporting files which are being used by main JS. The web clients always call main JS.
Now, I want to bundle all the files before deploying and want to keep them separate for development purpose. What is the best possible way to bundle these scripts?

Comment: based on your tag of [tag:requirejs] why do you want to bundle? The whole point of using requirejs is that you only pull down what you need IF it is needed.

Comment: If there are 20 files, I ll categories into relevant categories  and I ll make 3-4 bundle groups against each category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RequireJS comes with an [optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) which is designed to take care of most of the issues that come up with optimizing a RequireJS setup.

For instance this configuration would bundle an entire application into a single minified file:

```
({
    appDir: "../",
    baseUrl: "scripts",
    dir: "../../appdirectory-build",
    modules: [
        {
            name: "main"
        }
    ]
})
```

It reads the `main` module, finds all dependencies and bundles all that into a file located in the directory specified by the `dir` parameter.

What configuration to use really depends on the specifics of each project. Bundling everything into a single file is not necessarily the best method, etc. I suggest reading the documentation of the optimizer and asking specific questions if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If you really simply just want to bundle those files into a single file, you could simply use cat from your deploy script:

```
MAIN=main.js
PLUGINS=plugin1.js plugin2.js plugin3.js
cat $PLUGINS $MAIN >bundle.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You could minify the main js file along with all the other js files it is using.

Try : [Minify Javascript Online / Online JavaScript Packer](http://jscompress.com/%E2%80%8E)

Minification will make it difficult for others to read or change your code. Also performance will be improved.